# How to pass a (changing) variable between two view controllers?

Tags: swift, variables, uiviewcontroller

I have two view controllers. `VC1` & `VC2`. `VC1` is passing a variable which keeps changing & updating every second on `VC1`, in my case, it is the nearest beacon which is handled by a method in `VC1`.

`VC1` code:

```swift
  var id: Int = 0 // initializing

  // send data to VC2
  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard let vc2 = segue.destination as? navigationScreenVC else { return }
      vc2.id2 = id 
    }
```

`VC2` code:

```swift
  var id2: Int = 0

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print(VC2) 
  }
```

It is working where it sends the first value it encounters, but not when the value keeps changing, so I want that to be sent as soon as it triggers a change.

I tried to do `didSet{}` but it doesn't work that way.

Comment: the variable updates on VC1? You can have a reference to the second view controller and update it like you did on every change.

Comment: I'd suggest adding a breakpoint on `vc2.id2 = id` and check whether it's always reachable or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a delegate pattern.

In VC2:

```swift
protocol VC2Delegate: AnyObject {
  var id2: Int { get }
}

class VC2 {
  weak var delegate: VC2Delegate?

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print(delegate?.id2)
  }
}
```

In VC1:

```swift
class VC1: UIViewController, VC2Delegate {
...
  var id2: Int = 0 

  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard let vc2 = segue.destination as? navigationScreenVC else { return }
    vc2.delegate = self
  }
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A ViewController should not be managing stuff after it stopped being visible. You should managing this in a separate class and waiting for updates from a delegate, lets say:

```
protocol BeaconUpdateListener : AnyObject {
    func currentBeaconIdWasUpdated(to newValue: Int)
}

class BeaconManager {
    struct DelegateWrapper {
        weak var delegate : BeaconUpdateListener?
    }

    static let delegates = [DelegateWrapper]()
    static var currentId : Int = -1 {
        didSet {
            delegates.forEach { (delegate) in
                delegate.delegate?.currentBeaconIdWasUpdated(to: currentId)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sample code, missing details. You could make your own or update this one. Now, having that data outside your UI code makes it easier to use from anywhere else, and update that code in the future. This way, you "subscribe" to id updates like this:

```
BeaconManager.delegates.append(OBJECT_THAT_NEEDS_TO_BE_NOTIFIED)
```

... update your id like this:

```
BeaconManager.currentId = 65421687543152
```

... and wait for updates like this:

```
class VC2 : ViewController, BeaconUpdateListener {
    func currentBeaconIdWasUpdated(to newValue: Int) {
        // Do stuff once i receive the update
    }
    // ...
}
```